# Objective-C to Swift 3 Method Name Change Issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to use a method from Objective-C in Swift 3, but Swift 3 is translating the signature to something invalid for the compiler.

```
- (void)doWhenReady:(void(^)(void))block onDone:(ErrorCallback)callback;
```

Gets translated to

```
do(whenReady: ()->(), onDone: ErrorCallback)
```

Where `do` becomes the keyword `do` and invalid syntax for the method. What solutions do I have to fix this without refactoring the Objective-C code?

Comment: you could add one objective-c class to your projects that wraps the method call and give the wrapping method a swift compatible name.

Answer (score 0):

In the Swift expression `do(whenReady...`, write `do` with backtick characters around it.